# Show variable value in the dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

I need show a value in an dialog after execute a method that I invoke in the commandbutton but the dialog don't show the variable value.
The variable value is calculate inside the commandbutton.

Managed bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class OrderBean implements Serializable {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }  

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void eventicus(ActionEvent event) {
        this.name ="Value";
    }
}
```

xhtml document

```
        <h:commandButton actionListener="#{orderBean.calculate()}"  value="Show" oncomplete="PF('dlg2').show();"  />

    <p:dialog id="modalDialog" header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg2" >                 
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px">                
            <h4><h:outputText value="#{orderBean.name}" /></h4>  
        </h:panelGrid>          
        <p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="Submit" oncomplete="PF('dlg2').hide();"/>                   
    </p:dialog>
```

When I click in the commandbutton the dialog is empty.

Comment: I think you need to add a [update="modalDialog"] attribute inside your commandButton

Comment: Thanks Leo. I was helpful.

Comment: Yes it worked, when add attribute "update".

Answer (score 1):

1 I think you need to add a [update="modalDialog"] attribute inside your commandButton